# Limpiar JTablel y volver a cargar datos

Tags: java

Resulta que estoy haciendo un proyecto con java utilizando un JFrame para un formulario y una tabla.
Tengo un para llenar el formulario y la tabla utilizo el mismo **ResultSet** y al momento de guardar al formulario lo vuelvo a llamar con un metodo que comienza toda la aplicación esto por regla de negocio, entonces el formulario y la tabla se debe actualizar pero únicamente se actualiza el formulario, la tabla queda igual, hasta que finalizo la ejecución y la vuelvo a iniciar es donde se muestra la tabla correctamente, pero esto no debe de ser, parece ser como si la tabla esta guardando temporalmente los registros anteriores, aun que cierre la ventana de la tabla y se abra, vuelve a mostrarse igual, intente limpiarla con **tableModel.removeRow(0);** pero ya no vuelve a cargar nada.

Esto es como obtengo los datos y los guardo para imprimirlos en el formulario, y despues de obtener el ResultSet lo utilizo para la tabla.

```
public Object[][] obtenerDatos(String colaborador, String rol) {
    Object matrizDatos[][] = null;
    ShieldModel shieldModel = new ShieldModel();
    try {
        ResultSet rs = shieldModel.obtenerShieldByRol(colaborador, rol);
        tableController.cerrar();
        tableController.mostrarTable();
        tableController.mostrarRegistros(rs);
        int cantFilas = obtenerCount(colaborador, rol);
        int cantColumnas = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        Object[][] matriz = new Object [cantFilas][cantColumnas];
        if(rs.last()){//Nos posicionamos al final
            cantFilas = rs.getRow();//sacamos la cantidad de filas/registros
            rs.beforeFirst();//nos posicionamos antes del inicio (como viene por defecto)
        }
        int indice = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            matriz[indice][0] = rs.getString(1);
            matriz[indice][1] = rs.getInt(2);
            matriz[indice][2] = rs.getString(3);
            indice++;
        }
        matrizDatos = matriz;
        matriz1 = matrizDatos;
        rs.close();
        ConexionBD.cerrarSesion();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return matrizDatos;
}
```

Aqui es donde tengo lo necesario para crear e imprimir los registros.

```
public void mostrarTable() {
    tableView.TableView();
}


public void mostrarRegistros(ResultSet rs) {
    Vector<Object> fila;

    for (int i = tableView.getDTM().getRowCount(); i > 0; i--) {
        tableView.getDTM().removeRow(i - 1);
    }
    try {
        //ResultSet rs = shieldModel.obtenerShieldByRol(colaborador, rol);
        //ResultSet rs1 = rs;
        while (rs.next()) {

            fila = new Vector<Object>();
            fila.add(rs.getString(1));
            fila.add(rs.getString(2));
            fila.add(rs.getString(3));

            tableView.getDTM().addRow(fila);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        System.out.println(e2.getMessage());
    }
}

public void cerrar() {
    tableView.setVisible(false);
}
```

Y con esto vuelvo a llamar TODO pero la tabla no se actualiza solo el form, pero el rs.String de la tabla si me trae el dato actualizado, solo que no lo muestra.

```
obtenerDatos(colaboradorG, rolG);
```

Comment: probá con `tuModelo.setRowCount(0);`

Comment: Ya lo probé, si limpia los registros pero ya no vuelve a mostrar los nuevos, se queda en blanco

Comment: pero lo tenes que poner al principio, o sea antes de llenar la tabla, de forma que el modelo ya tiene que estar limpio al momento de llenar la tabla

Comment: mmm no, no me respeta la instrucción, la agrego sobre esta linea, antes de realizar el **ResultSet**.
    `tableView.getDTM().setRowCount(0);`
    `obtenerDatos(colaboradorG, rolG);`